# Shared pointer (this)

Tags: c++, oop, this, shared-ptr

I have got an exception throw :0x74AC4192 in main.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_weak_ptr at memory location 0x001AF0D0.

in

```
Gasstation::Gasstation(int n,int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        pumps_.push_back(std::make_shared<Pumplace>());
    }
    cashregisters_ = std::make_shared<Cashregister> (shared_from_this(), m);
}
```

I also used this in the header :

```
class Gasstation : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Gasstation>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Where does it crash _exactly_? Did you use a debugger? Did you look at the stack trace? Which tools (IDE/compiler/versions etc.) do you use? We need more code, the problem could be somewhere in the `Pumplace` or the `Cashregister` classes or even elsewhere.

Comment: From the notes section of [this `shared_from_this` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this): "in particular, `shared_from_this` cannot be called during construction of `*this`". In short, you can't call `shared_from_this()` in the constructor.

Comment: I recommend you take some time to think a little: Do you really *need* `Gasstation` to "enable shared from this"? And, as a way to solve this specific problem, do each "cash register" need to have a shared pointer to its gas station? Can't it have a normal non-shared pointer (or perhaps even a reference)? Think of it from an ownership perspective instead: The gas station owns one or more cash registers, but the cash registers doesn't own the gas station. I always recommend that you look at the smart pointers from the ownership perspective instead or as simple self-deleting pointers.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please don't use anonymous one-letter variables like `n` or `m` for arguments. Please try to come up with a name that describes their use. It will make your code much easier to read and understand by others, or even you in a couple of years time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code here, is that you are calling `shared_from_this()` within the constructor of the class itself, where strictly speaking, it has not been "made shared" yet. The constructor is called *before* a smart pointer to the object exists. To follow your example, if creating a `shared_ptr` to `Gasstation`:

```
std::shared_ptr<Gasstation> gasStation = std::make_shared<Gasstation>(5,10);
//gasStation is available as a smart pointer, only from this point forward
```

Its a limitation of `enable_shared_from_this` that `shared_from_this` cannot be called in a constructor.

One solution, though not as elegant, is to have a public method that sets the cashregisters_ variable. The method can be called after construction:

```
Gasstation::Gasstation(int n, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        pumps_.push_back(std::make_shared<Pumplace>());
    }
    cashregisters_ = std::make_shared<Cashregsiter>(m);
}

Gasstation::initialise_cashregisters()
{
    cashregisters_->set_gasstation(shared_from_this());    
}

//driver code
std::shared_ptr<Gasstation> gasStation = std::make_shared<Gasstation>(5, 10);
gasStation->initialise_cashregisters();
```

This solution will require you to remember to call initialise_cashregisters every time you initialise Gasstation.

Short of that, your options are limited, and you may have to rethink your design. Have you considered using raw pointers-to-Gasstation in Cashregister instead of smart pointers? If cashregister_ is a private variable and will never exist beyond the lifetime of the Gasstation it is assigned to, using raw pointers may be a safe and elegant alternative.